# rails - Auto create tasks after creating a project (after_create)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, after-create

a newbie here. Just started to learn development. Any help would be greatly appreciated

I have two models  Project and Task. Each project will have 7 tasks. I want rails to auto create my 7 tasks after I create a project.

My Task Controller

```
def create
@task = Task.new(task_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @task.save
    format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

```
def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this.

#### 1. Via callbacks

You can use callbacks in the Project model. Personally I do not recommend this approach since it this is not the intended use of callbacks, but it may work for you.

```
class Project < class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_tasks

private

  def create_tasks
    # Logic here to create the tasks. For example:
    # tasks.create!(title: "Some task")
  end
end
```

#### 2. Nested attributes

You can build the child objects into the form and Rails will automatically create the child objects for you. Check out [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). This is more involved than using callbacks.

#### 3. Use a form object

A form object can be a nice middle ground between callbacks and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but it raises the complexity a notch. [Read up more about form objects here](https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/158-form-objects-in-rails). There is also a nice [Rails Casts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects) on the topic, but it requires subscription.

There are other ways to do this as well, so it's up to you to find the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use [Observer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html). This is more like callback.

But this is a great way to reduce the clutter that normally comes when the model class is burdened with functionality that doesn't pertain to the core responsibility of the class

```
class ProjectObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(project)
    #add the logic to create tasks
  end
end
```

Comment: Observers were removed from Rails, and require the addition of a separate gem. The very reason they were removed is because they made code ambiguous, and it became less clear where the code and necessary business logic lived. They certainly have their use cases, but this is not one of them.